# DisplayName the Reporting Services encoding characters in firefox

Tags: c#, .net, firefox, service, reporting

My problem is that I generate the pdf with ReportViewer Dynamic

Example:

```
                > StringBuilder nameReport= new StringBuilder();
                > nameReport.Append(report.Chartname.ToString());
                > nameReport.Append("-");
                > nameReport.Append(year.ToString());
                > nameReport.Append("-");
                > nameReport.Append(month.ToString());
                > rv.ServerReport.DisplayName = nameReport.ToString();
```

Output:

1. Name Report in IE = TotalVisits-2014-01.PDF
2. Name Report in Chrome = TotalVisits-2014-01.PDF
3. Name report in Firefox = TotalVisits%2D;01%2D01.PDF

Anyone have an idea about the enconding Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [percent encoding or URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), basically, in an URL instead of displaying a dash (-), it encodes it as %2D;, this is mainly because certain characters may have an special meaning (reserved) and when they appear in an URL outside their special meaning, they should be encoded so as they're not confused.